# While checking Angular version, shows incomplete output

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After installing npm, I was checking angular version using command 'ng -version'. It shows ANGULAR CLI output. But, there is one column shows 'Angular: undefined'. I don't why it shows like this?

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.5
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: undefined
  ...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.803.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         8.3.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.3.5 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          8.3.5 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.803.5 (cli-only)
```

Comment: can you restart your machine and try again with ng --version

Comment: Its nothing problemattic in that, Are you facing any issue due to this?